# React is giving error: export 'useId' (imported as 'React') was not found in 'react'

Tags: reactjs, import, export

I've created a new react app using webpack. It is showing me this error I've written minimum code as of now.
The code giving error is:

```
import React from 'react';
import AppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';

export default function Navigation() {
  return (
    <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
        <AppBar position="static">
            <Toolbar variant="dense">
                <Typography variant="h6" color="inherit" component="div">
                Photos
                </Typography>
            </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is an issue with version 5.2.0 . There's already a GitHub issue: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/29860

Comment: Okay got it, thank you. @BenjaminM

Comment: anyone else curious about what these "__SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR__YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED" is about?

Answer (score 0):

use id is a build in hook that provided by react it self, it's for generating unique IDs that can be passed to accessibility attributes.

import { useId } from 'react';

const passwordHintId = useId();

You can check react official website for the reference

https://react.dev/reference/react/useId

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the first import in this

```
import * from React
```

That can maybe work